# Salesforce for Outlook mail upload failed

Tags: community, upload, salesforce-for-outlook, outlook

I'm having an issue to upload e-mail/s from my Outlook to Salesforce via the Salesforce for Outlook plugin. The issue happens only for particular account 'Streamlined Marketing Systems Inc' and sometimes the emails to this account can be successfully uploaded, other times the upload fail. Here is what I received when the mail failed to be uploaded. 
Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:

emailtosalesforce@t-2yfr1nfp936028pcse8ki7zwtnqhvex9q0n0i92rqtqa2de8cr.3-1fm77eac.na20.le.salesforce.com (emailtosalesforce@t-2yfr1nfp936028pcse8ki7zwtnqhvex9q0n0i92rqtqa2de8cr.3-1fm77eac.na20.le.salesforce.com) 
A problem occurred during the delivery of this message to this e-mail address. Try sending this message again. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.

The following organization rejected your message: server-16.tower-188.messagelabs.com.

Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: EMP-LDN-EXCH01.emp.internal.com

emailtosalesforce@t-2yfr1nfp936028pcse8ki7zwtnqhvex9q0n0i92rqtqa2de8cr.3-1fm77eac.na20.le.salesforce.com 
server-16.tower-188.messagelabs.com #553-Message filtered. Refer to the Troubleshooting page at 553-http://www.symanteccloud.com/troubleshooting for more 553 information. (#5.7.1) ##

Could you please advise how to resolve this issue.

Regards,

Dilyan

Comment: Hi Dylan, did you check my answer below to see if it helped you with your issue?

Answer (score 3):

The message is from email scanner (antivirus) in between your Outlook client and the Salesforce server.

Per the URL contained in your question (https://support.symantec.com/en_US/cloud/troubleshooting.64305.html), error #553 indicates the message was filtered and returned because of it having a high spam score. Evaluating those messages that fail and see what the trend is among them. They could have spam like content, a virus embedded in an attachment or even a misconfiguration issue with your mail server.

There are really so many different possible resolutions, and I would recommend starting with the easiest as previously mentioned above. Examine all of the emails that were bounced back and determine the pattern between them. If there is no pattern, then ask your company's IT to assist and check their mail servers to see if they are configured as an open relay or have been black listed online.

Good luck.